# Site's performance slows over time until Apache is restarted

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, memcached

I'm running a Django app w/ Nginx and Apache.  All our static media is stored on S3, and basically it takes a while for the app to check if thumbnails have been created every time a page is loaded.  To alleviate this problem, I'm caching the output of the templates w/ memcached.  Over the course of an hour or two, the site's speed goes down significantly, until I restart apache, and then all is good for a little while.

I have very little sysadmin experience, and was hoping somebody could at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: are there any errors in the error log for the site or the php log (if you have php logging enabled)?

Answer (score 1):

Why is Apache part of this at all? nginx->fastcgi->django is *very* capable and dropping apache will free up a whole raft of resources.

Answer (score 0):

First up you could run top .. to examine if your experiencing high load. If you've no real load but you are seeing a high IO WAIT % then it's possibly an IO issue.

You could install the sysstat package. This comes with sar which is a handy util for examing performance counters.

http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/52570

A short yet resonible article on using SAR.

You could also be having apache processes becoming stuck .. ps aux will list the processes running on the machine .. you could use this to see how many apache threads you start with .. if they seem to continue to grow and not die this could also lead to degraded performance.

T